# Pass props to App and redirect in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

I am trying to redirect any route on my Next.js app to '/login' in case there is no token present in cookies.

The highest order component the app has is _document.js. This is it:

```
import Document from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';
import nextCookies from 'next-cookies';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
    const { token } = nextCookies(ctx);

    try {
      console.log(token);
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App token={token} {...props} />)
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        )
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the token using the 'next-cookies' package and the token is getting logged to the console due to the `console.log` statement in the `try` block.

Although it seems that I am passing it down to the `<App />` component, I cannot see it in the devtools. Also, the `<App />` component is not in the file tree. How would I be able to get the token in props and redirect in App?